# Javascript-style object methods in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, methods

In Javascript, I can do this:

```
var person = {
  name: 'Joe',
  age:  '35',
  speak: function(){
    return 'o hai i am joe'
  }
}
```

Then I can call that method:

```
person.speak()
'o hai i am joe'
```

I know this can be done with classes in Python, and presumably that's the right way to go.

Nonetheless, I'm curious -- is there some way to add a function as a value in a Python dictionary?

Comment: The javascript version does more than that, it defines a whole object. If you want real objects in Python, not just lumped-together values and functions (which don't have access to th latter), you'll have to write classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
person = {
  'name': 'Joe',
  'age':  '35',
  'speak': lambda: 'o hai i am joe',
}
```

However, in Python (unlike JavaScript), attribute and [] access are different. To execute speak, write

```
person['speak']()
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the key differences between javascript and python is the handling of the target object in the method's namespace.  In javascript, `this` is set as needed when the method is *called*, but in python, `self` is determined in a combination of class creation time (turning functions into instancemethods) and when the attribute is accessed (binding the im_self property on the instancemethod).  Even if you were to use attribute access only, overcoming this difference is a bit tricky when you want to bind instance methods to individual instances, instead of the class.

```
import functools
class JSObject(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        """
        if the attribute is on the instance, and the target of that is
        callable, bind it to self, otherwise defer to the default getattr.
        """
        self_dict = object.__getattribute__(self, '__dict__')
        if attr in self_dict and callable(self_dict[attr]):
            return functools.partial(self_dict[attr], self)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> foo = JSObject()
>>> foo.bar = 'baz'
>>> foo.bar
'baz'
>>> foo.quux = lambda self: self.bar
>>> foo.quux
<functools.partial object at 0x7f8bae264ba8>
>>> foo.quux()
'baz'
```

Making the above class a bit more `dict`like is a separate issue, and in my opinion, not the best "feature" of JavaScript to emulate, but supposing we wanted that "anyways", we would probably start by subclassing `dict`, and once again overloading `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, which I will leave as an exercise.

Comment: This is fascinating, thanks. I'd never looked at `functools`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def test():
    print "hello"

testDict = {"name" : "Joe", "age" : 35, "speak" : test}

testDict["speak"]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, either by defining the functions ahead of time:

```
def speak_function(txt):
  print txt

person = {
  'speak': speak_function
}
```

Or possibly by using lambdas (in the case of simple returns):

```
person = {
  'speak': lambda x: x
}
```

Comment: return is not valid in lambdas, its implicit.